# Code that works in 8.4 is causing crash in 8.6, is there a better way to implement the functionality

Tags: tcl

I have a Tcl utility that makes it easy to ensure a snippet of code run at the time control flow leaves the current scope (of the `proc`).  It crashes in Tcl 8.6.6, so I'm wondering if there is a "better" way to implement the functionality in Tcl 8.6?

An example usage is:

```
proc test {file} {
   set fh [open $file]
   ::Util::Defer [list close $fh]
   # ... do a bunch of stuff
   # and even if we hit an error
   # [close $fh] will be evaluated as we return
   # from the proc
}
```

It's worked great in Tcl 8.4, and I use it all over my code.

As I'm still coming up to speed on all the functionality available in Tcl 8.6, I'm asking how should the `::Util::Defer` proc be written to best take advantage of Tcl 8.6?

Here is the 8.4 implementation:

```
namespace eval ::Util {}
proc ::Util::Defer_impl {cmd args} {
  uplevel 1 $cmd
}
proc ::Util::Defer {cmd} {
  set vname _u_defer_var
  # look for a unique variable name
  while {[uplevel 1 [list info vars $vname]] != ""} {
    set vname ${vname}_
  }
  uplevel 1 [list set $vname $cmd]
  # when the variable is unset, trigger a call to the command
  uplevel 1 [list trace add variable $vname unset [list ::Util::Defer_impl $cmd]]
  # return a chunk of code enabling the user to cancel this if desired
  return [list variable $vname unset [list ::Util::Defer_impl $cmd]]
}
```

*Edited to add:*
I appreciate the answers.  To be honest, I already have other syntactic sugar for a file handle, this:

```
proc test {file} {
   set fh [::Util::LocalFileHandle $file]
   # do stuff
}
```

I was just hoping more for a generic solution to the `::Util::Defer` - because I occasionally have two or three uses (at different locations) in the same proc.  Yes, I'm leaving out the error handling if the doesn't exist or isn't readable.

*Note:* I have reported the bug to ActiveState and filed a [bug at core.tcl.tk](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview/551061651d07944a19c767065).

*Edited to add buggy code:* This is the Tcl code that causes a crash for me, it is slightly pared down to the essence (as opposed to being the full-blown `::Util::Defer`).

```
# ---------------begin script-------------------
package require Itcl

proc ::try_uplevel {} {
  return [uplevel 1 [list ::info vars _u_defer_var]]
}

itcl::class ::test_class {
  constructor {} {}

  public proc test_via_proc {} {
    ::try_uplevel
  }
}

::test_class::test_via_proc
# ---------------end script-------------------
```

Comment: It seems that there is no such problem with Tcl 8.6.0 under Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have 8.6.0, only 8.6.4 and 8.6.6, for Red Hat 6.6.

Comment: Hmm, I'd use `set vname _[expr rand()]` as an initial guess for deferred variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the weekend this heavyweight solution came to mind.  It leverages the `itcl::local` functionality to achieve the same effect.  It does depend on `Itcl` - but since the problem is an interaction with `Itcl`, that seems a reasonable solution, even though it is not purely Tcl.

```
itcl::class Defer_impl {
  constructor {cmd} {} {
    set _to_eval $cmd
  }
  destructor {
    uplevel 1 $_to_eval
  }
  private variable _to_eval {}
}

proc ::Util::Defer {cmd} {
  uplevel 1 [list itcl::local ::Defer_impl #auto $cmd]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you describe is a supported one; it shouldn't crash (and indeed *I can't reproduce the crash* with 8.6.3 or the tip of the 8.6 support branch). The only problem it has is that if you have an error during the `close` (or any other deferred script) it won't report it, as you can see from this snippet (`%` is prompt):

```
% apply {{} {
    ::Util::Defer [list error boo]
    puts hi
}}
hi
%
```

This is part of why I went to quite a bit of effort to provide a `try` command in 8.6. With that, you can do this:

```
proc test {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    try {
        # Do stuff with $f
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}
```

It also takes care of tricky things like stitching errors thrown inside the body and the `finally` clause together (the body exception info is in the `-during` option of the `finally` clause's error exception info) so that if both places error you can find out about both.

```
% catch {
    try {
        error a
    } finally {
        error b
    }
} x y
1
% puts $x
b
% puts $y
-errorstack {INNER {returnImm b {}}} -errorcode NONE -errorinfo {b
    while executing
"error b"} -errorline 5 -during {-code 1 -level 0 -errorstack {INNER {returnImm a {}}} -errorcode NONE -errorinfo {a
    while executing
"error a"} -errorline 3} -code 1 -level 0
```

---

Personally, I'd be more inclined to write this:

```
proc withreadfile {varName filename body} {
    upvar 1 $varName f
    set f [open $filename]
    try {
        return [uplevel 1 $body]
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}

proc test {file} {
    withreadfile fh $file {
        # Do stuff with $fh
    }
}
```

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks, I like the new `try/finally` and will start using that, but was hoping for a drop-in replacement for the syntactic sugar of `::Util::Defer`.  This is probably a bug in the build we're getting, or some environment, or... I don't know.  I may have to build Tcl/Tk/IncrTcl myself to see if I can still reproduce this.  Using the debug libraries provided (and the optimized) I definitely get a null pointer and a seg fault...

Comment: @TreyJackson IncrTcl? That might be related to the problem. It digs its tentacles rather deeply into Tcl, and could have put things in a weird state. What you're doing *should* work; it is supported at least until the end of the 8.* series. (I plan something different for 9.0 - more focused around the "stack frame going away" use case - as local variable traces are otherwise problematic for advanced compilation.)

Comment: I believe it is intimately involved with IncrTcl, as it only fails for me when I use it from a `proc` (not `method`) from within an IncrTcl class.  I'll update my answer to have the code from the bug report so as to be explicit about what isn't working.

Comment: it was an Incr bug, it's been fixed in the 4.0.6 by dgp.

Answer (score 0):

Untested code (this exact snippet, I've used this pattern many times):

```
proc test file {
    try {
        open $file
    } on ok fh {
        # do stuff with fh
        # more stuff 
    } finally {
        catch {close $fh}
    }
}
```

should be about the same. Regardless of whether you handle errors with the `try` structure or not, (or whether you get errors or not) the code in the `finally` clause is run when it ends. If you want to be able to cancel the action, use a simple `if` inside the clause.

**Edit**

In case one wants to see any errors generated when the channel is closed, it's a bad idea to just wrap it in a `catch`, which is necessary if the file couldn't be opened and the channel-id variable wasn't created. Alternatives include:

- Checking for existence: `if {[info exists fh]} {close $fh}`
- Propagate the closing error: using the `result` and `options` variable name arguments to `catch`.

Comment: Your code will try to `close` an unset variable on failure to open. You handle that by `catch`ing, which will lose errors from closing a pipeline…

Comment: Guilty as charged, my lord.